# How to code a backup function into database application with Delphi, using an Access db

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe2, database-backups

I have developed an database application with Delphi XE2 using an Access DB, now the problem is that I never added any backup and restore function into the application. The database will take a long time to get big, as it will only record about 30 records per day. So what I want to know is how to I write a function in Delphi that for example duplicates the database to a specific location, selected by the user. And also how to restore a backup from a location selected by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To backup and resstore an access db you must copy the `.accdb` (or `.mdb` for older versions) file to the location which you want. Just be ensure of close the existing connections to the db. To copy the file you can use the [`TFile.Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.Copy) method.

Comment: And don't forget to close any connections to the database before making a bakcup-copy!

Comment: And don't forget to make the file writeable if you restore it from a readonly medium such as a CD or DVD. All sorts of fun error messages with a readonly database if your code isn't expecting it.

Comment: And don't forget to compress/repair the DB file before you make a backup!